# How to nest IF block with OR statement in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm looking for some help with this little code that I'm using in Google spreadsheet:

```
 =ArrayFormula(IF(OR(F2:F="Cancelled",G2:G="Cancelled"),"Cancelled",IF(F2:F="Finished",20,)+IF(G2:G="Finished",20,)))
```

For some reason it works if I use this code without calling multiple rows:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(F2="Cancelled",G2="Cancelled"),"Cancelled",IF(F2="Finished",20,)+IF(G2="Finished",20,)))
```

Does anyone have an idea which is the correct way to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` merges all `TRUE`s to one value  and does not maintain array size.

You need to use `+` instead of `OR`;  Like,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((F2:F="Cancelled")+(G2:G="Cancelled"), "Cancelled".... ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is working perfect,
 Thanks so much. Regards

Comment: @James Accept my answer by clicking ☑ on the left of this post.

Comment: Sorry about that, is my first question. Thanks James

Comment: @TheMaster Which symbol should be used instead of + for AND ?

Comment: @AdOne `*` for `AND`